# NextJS throws `"url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid"`

Tags: next.js

When i try to get a image from i receive this error:

```
"url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid
```

Happening only on production localhost works tho any idea what could be

Using nextjs `next": "^12.0.4"`

[image: Error example]